# Better way use @State or @ObservableObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, state

Hi everyone I have a question about @`State` vs `@ObservableObject` with `SwiftUI`

I have a view that contains a `LazyHGrid`
To have a **custom cell** of the `LazyHGrid` I preferred to create a new `struct` with the custom cell.

---

The view hierarchy is composed as follows:

`struct View1` -> `struct LazyHGrid` -> `struct LazyHGridCustomCell`

In **View1** I have a text that must be replaced with content of the **LazyHGridCustomCell** every time it is selected.

At this point in view of my hierarchy should I use `@State` & `@Binding` to update the text or would it be better `@ObservableObject`?

In case I wanted to use the `@State` wrapper I would find myself like this:

- `struct View1` (`@State`)
- `struct LazyHGrid` (`@Binding`)
- `struct LazyHGridCustomCell` (`@Binding`)

I was wondering if this is the right way or consider `@ObservableObject`

I created a code example based on my question .. It was created just to let you understand what I mean to avoid being misunderstood

I was wondering if it is right to create such a situation or use an `@ObservableObject`

In case this path is wrong can you show me an example of the right way to go to get the correct result?

Thanks for suggestion

---

```
struct View1: View {
    @State private var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
        LazyHGridView(name: $name)
    }
}

struct LazyHGridView: View { 
    @Binding var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyHGrid(rows: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 2)) {
            ForEach(reservationTimeItems) { item in
                LazyHGridCustomCell(name: $name)
            }
        }
    }
}
    
struct LazyHGridCustomCell: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Data Essentials in SwiftUI (WWDC 2020)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/) at 9:46, you should be using State because ObservableObject is for model data.

> State is designed for transient UI state that is local to a view. In
> this section, I want to move your attention to designing your model
> and explain all the tools that SwiftUI provides to you. Typically, in
> your app, you store and process data by using a data model that is
> separate from its UI. This is when you reach a critical point where
> you need to manage the life cycle of your data, including persisting
> and syncing it, handle side-effects, and, more generally, integrate it
> with existing components. This is when you should use
> ObservableObject. First, let's take a look at how ObservableObject is
> defined.